# Why the electrolyte is made up of the same metal which is being electro refined?

Tags: electrochemistry

For example for the electrorefining of Cu the electrolyte is CuSO4... WHY the salt of the same metal is used as an ELECTROLYTE..??

Answer (score 1):

Think about this the other way around.

Let's say you got the impure copper anode and nickel sulphate electrolyte.
When copper is oxidized something has to deposit in the cathode, but it won't be copper if there is no copper electrolyte.

It's also worth notice that the concentration of copper sulphate remains the same, or close to, so you can re-use the solution.